# Vimscript - Loading function(s) from another .vim file

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, functions, plugin-system, multiple-files

I'm forking an old vim plugin (effectively dead since 2018) that needed some love. Once I got to the `.vim` file, I noticed that the functions were *all* defined in there, which made the file unreasonably huge and messy. Is there any way to move these functions to different files for the sake of maintenance?

Comment: for vimscript, there are autoloadable functions, see `:h autoload`, for vim9script you can use `import`s see `:h vim9-import`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Yeah, autoload is what you want... In short, you need to store them somewhere under an `autoload/` directory and call them using a `my#plg#myfunc()` syntax (assuming `myfunc()` is defined in `autoload/my/plg.vim`). For maximum efficiency (during Vim startup), make sure functions from your auto-loaded file will only be called from mappings or user-commands, autocommands, filetype-specific plugins. That way, the autoload file will not be loaded at startup, but only when it's actually needed...

Answer (score 1):

See:

- [`:help autoload`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#autoload)
- [`:help write-library-script`](https://vimhelp.org/usr_41.txt.html#write-library-script)